# Calling a function with a dynamically allocated array pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to call the following function which should fill an array with sensors' data and return the number of detected sensors:

```
uint8_t ds18b20_read_all(uint8_t pin, ds_sensor_t *result)
```

How am I supposed to call it without knowing the number of sensors? I thought about:

```
ds_sensor_t *result = (ds_sensor_t *) malloc(NUM_OF_SENSORS * sizeof(ds_sensor_t));
uint8_t count = ds18b20_read_all(pin, result);
```

But again I don't know NUM_OF_SENSORS. Should I just choose a large enough number?

EDIT:
The source code of the function: https://github.com/SuperHouse/esp-open-rtos/blob/master/extras/ds18b20/ds18b20.c

Comment: Read the description of the function.

Comment: I think you can use `realloc` function every time you read data of new sensor. http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc It means that you can addyour sensors one by one to `result`

Comment: I think there should be a constant that says you max available mumber of sensors (something like MAX_NUM_OF_SENSORS). Or something like this... Do you have source code of function ds18b20_read_all ?

Comment: An [example is here](https://github.com/SuperHouse/esp-open-rtos/blob/master/extras/ds18b20/ds18b20.c).

Comment: The source code is available at https://github.com/SuperHouse/esp-open-rtos/blob/master/extras/ds18b20/ds18b20.c      The documentation says nothing about how to call  // Scan all ds18b20 sensors on bus and return its amount.
// Result are saved in array of ds_sensor_t structure.

Comment: @Sandro it's one call to get all data, so I cannot reallocate the array after the call

Comment: @WeatherVane this is the function itself, no an example on how to call.

Comment: `ds18b20_scan_devices` should return you the number of devices. Then you can use this information to read them all.

Comment: Surely you know how many sensors there are and have allocated an array large enough.

Comment: @Mouk you linked the same example ;)

Comment: As I can see in  the header file from github  there is the following comment before your function declaration : "The following are obsolete/deprecated APIs". So maybe it is better to try to use another functions?  
  https://github.com/SuperHouse/esp-open-rtos/blob/master/extras/ds18b20/ds18b20.h"

Comment: The definition of the function looks rather unsafe. There is no maximum in the read loop, so it would be defined by the maximum of devices on a onewire bus (whatever that is),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The header says, that the function you are asking about is an obsolete API. That usually means you should not be using it if replacement is provided:

// The following are obsolete/deprecated APIs
...
uint8_t ds18b20_read_all(uint8_t pin, ds_sensor_t *result);

I suspect it's deprecated for the very reason you have questions about:. It's unclear how to use it.

New APIs (below is one of them) has addr_count as a parameter:

bool ds18b20_read_temp_multi(int pin, ds18b20_addr_t *addr_list, int addr_count, float *result_list);

Comment: Ok, I missed that somehow. It makes sense.  I thought I missed something in the C language.

Answer (score 3):

Max sensors on 1-wire is 75. So you can have up to 75 ds18b20s attached. You can also query the wire to find out *how many* sensors are attached using `int ds18b20_scan_devices(int pin, ds18b20_addr_t *addr_list, int addr_count);` set addr_count = 75.